# How do I GET and POST at the same time with Curl?

Tags: php, api, rest, curl

I have a working "API" but noticed it's not REST because I was just using `POST` requests passing a `mode` variable for determining which action to do. So now I'm changing the conditions that matched the `mode` variable so that they match instead the `HTTP Method`. But here comes my problem.

In every request I submit by POST a `user` and a `HMAC` of the `data + user private key`. So in the case I wanted to get the data of a determined `id`, I used `curl` for creating a request with those variables and POST it to the URL `api/id`. Then there is a RewriteRule for changing that to `api.php?id=$1`, so in my `api.php` I had both data, the `id` via `GET` and the auth info via `POST`.

So... if for getting a user's data I need to use  the`GET` method now, how can I submit (POST) the auth info as well?

---

How was before (working but not as a REST API should work)

**api.php**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    if ($_POST['mode'] === "get"){
        get_data($_GET["id"]);
    }
}
```

**client.php**

```
    $params = array('user' => 'qwerty', 'hash' => 'jFJKSAFhskafa');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/123";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($output, true);
}
```

---

How it should be:

**api.php**

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "GET"){
    get_data($_GET["id"]);
}
```

**client.php**

```
    $params = array('user' => 'qwerty', 'hash' => 'jFJKSAFhskafa');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/api/123";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

  //-------->>>> How do I send the params now?

    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $data = json_decode($output, true);
}
```

Comment: Do a POST request and set a query string on the URL being requested for the GET behavior.

Comment: @Ultimater but the problem of doing it that way, is that the request to the `api` will be using `POST` and that's not correct. It must be using `GET` because is a reading operation. If it was for creating a new record, then `POST` would be ok. `DELETE` for removing a record and `PUT` for updating.

Comment: Why not treat the request as POST first, then redirect after the POST is done to a GET request. The POST/REDIRECT/GET behavior is a very common design pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: So, you want to make a HTTP GET request, but do not want the params to be visible in the URL, am I correct?

Comment: @PrabhasGupte just solved it, read my answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are two ways of handling this situation.

- Instead of submitting the authentication info via `POST`, create custom headers with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER'`
- Trick cURL, submitting `POST` data but defining `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` to `GET`.